# how to choose k columns and 1/0 for each column for maximum intersection in a random 1/0 table

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

for an algorithm I'm building, I need to find the intersection that will give me the maximum number of rows.

suppose you have a table with n columns and m rows willed randomly with 1/0.

I'm trying to find a way to choose k columns and 1/0 for each column, where the intersection between the 1's / 0's in those columns will give me the maximum rows.

example:

```
table: 
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
```

if i need to choose 1 column: ill choose the first with - 0: which will give me 4 rows.

so if i need to choose 2 columns, the result will be the first column - 0, and the last column 1. which will give me 3 rows.

if i need to choose 3 columns, the result will be:
first 0, second - 1, last 1.
which will give me 2 rows.

also, if you suggest a solution, it will be great to also say why is the solution correct, why are those the best k solumns?

cause bard gave me a greedy solution and im not sure its the best one.
i am not sure that if ill each time add another column that creates the highest intersection, at the end of the process ill have the best solution

hope its clear, thanx a lot!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the intersection that will give me the maximum number of rows." and how you arrive at " if i need to choose 2 columns, the result will be the first column - 0, and the last column 1. which will give me 3 rows."

Comment: This looks like some variation of MAX-SAT problem, so is probably intractable.

Comment: Echoing @n.m.couldbeanAI I'm 95% sure I could swing a reduction from biclique finding, which is NP-hard. Definitely the greedy solution does not always achieve the optimum.

Comment: @itprorh66 the intersection that will give me the maximum number of rows - means the num of rows that the intersection of the chosen columns and values will give. as in the example.
2. to your second question, i just looked at the table. (game a simple example)